# Publishing web app for remote event receivers

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver

i created a fresh sharepoint add-in for my scenario am creating a remote event receiver,when i published the latter it get this error :
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.